# How can I check an Exception object type in Android?

Tags: android, exception, instanceof, typeof

I would like to check an exception object type in Android that I am returning from a function along with other data.  I was using the following however this would also trigger for the subclass SSLPeerUnverifiedException which is something I don't want to occur.

```
if (args.exception instanceof SSLException)) {
    // TODO Exception Error
```

I then changed this to the following however I thought there maybe a better comparison check rather than comparing strings.

```
String exceptionName = args.exception.getClass().getSimpleName();
if (exceptionName.equals("SSLException")) {
   // TODO Exception Error
```

Answer (score 1):

Would it work if you caught both SSLException and SSLPeerUnverifiedException explicitly, and in the catch block of SSLPeerUnverifiedException you'd just rethrow the exception?